# Bounded, closed $\implies$ compact

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I'm having issues with part b).

If i were to use a covering arguement, because $[a,b]$ is a compact set (proved in lectures) then $\forall$ open coverings of $[a,b]$ $ \exists$ a finite subcover. All  of these open coverings cover K and all have corresponding finite subcovers that cover K, as $K \subset [a,b]$. However if $K \subsetneq [a,b]$ there will be open coverings of $K$ that do not cover $[a,b]$, so how do i know these open coverings have corresponding finite subcoverss?

Comment: Add $K^C$ to the cover.

Comment: where $K^C$ means the complement of $K$.

Comment: If I allow $K^C$ to be in the open covering the union of $K^C$ with any arbitrary open cover of $[a,b]$ will just be $K^C$ which is not  an arbitrary open cover. Do you mean $K^C \cap (a,b)$?

Comment: you should start with an arbitrary open cover of $K$, not $[a,b]$, and then try to find a finite subcover. the idea is to try to extend your open covering to cover $[a,b]$, use it's compactness to choose a finite subcover, and then hope to find a finite subcover of K using this.

Comment: @relep Do you mind having a look at my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Let {$A_{\alpha}$}$_{\alpha \in J} $ be an open cover for $K$:

$\displaystyle K \subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha \in J} A_{\alpha}$

{$A_{\alpha}$}$_{\alpha \in I}$ is an arbitrary open covering for $[a,b]$ where $I\subseteq J$ with

$I=J$\  ${\alpha}$ st. $A_\alpha$ is an open covering for $K$ but not $[a,b]$

$[a,b]\displaystyle  \subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_{\alpha}\implies [a,b]\displaystyle  \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^m A_{\alpha_i}$

i.e {$A_{\alpha_1},...,A_{\alpha_m}$} is a finite subcover for $[a,b]$ with

{${\alpha_1},...,{\alpha_m}$}$\subset I$ and also $\subset J$

as $K \subseteq [a,b]$, {$A_{\alpha_1},...,A_{\alpha_m}$} covers $K$ and {${\alpha_1},...,{\alpha_m}$} $\subset J$ and is finite, it is a finite subcover of $K$. Hence $K$ is compact.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. How do you justify the third line? $\{A_\alpha \mid \alpha\in J\}$ need not be a cover of $[a,b]$, as you observed in your OP. If this is the case, no subset of $\{A_\alpha \mid \alpha\in J\}$ will cover $[a,b]$ either. Perhaps I'm misinterpreting things here.  But, look at the collection $$C=\{A_j \mid \alpha\in J\} \cup\{K^C\}.$$ This is a cover of $[a,b]$ ($K^C$ is open since $K$ is closed). Take a finite subcollection of $C$ that covers $[a,b]$; this will also cover $K$. Toss out $K^C$, if it's there, and you have what you need.

Comment: @ David Mitra I am not saying {$A_{\alpha}$}$_{\alpha \in J}$ covers $[a,b]$ but {$A_{\alpha}$}$_{\alpha \in I}$ does.

Comment: But then, you'd want $J\subseteq I$.

Comment: @ David Mitra I'm saying there are "more" open coverings of K than [a,b]

Comment: @David Mitra And I have a finite collection of sets with $\alpha \in J$ that covers K

Comment: You definitely want to have $J \subseteq I$. (you want to "expand" your cover into a cover of $[a,b]$). To see a simple example of why your third line doesn't work, let's say $K=[2,3]$, $[a,b]=[0,5]$, $I= \mathbb{N}$ and $A_n=(1+\frac{1}{n},4-\frac{1}{n})$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ will indeed be an open cover of $K$ (since $K \subseteq A_2$ for example), but you clearly can't remove any element of $I$ to get an open cover of $[0,5]$.

And what do you mean by "there are more open coverings of $K$ then $[a,b]$"?.

Comment: @relep I understand what i've done wrong now. There are more open coverings of K than [a,b] as any cover of [a,b] covers K and there are covers of K that do not cover [a,b], but that is irrelevant as we are considering a single arbitrary open cover.